# Styling a variable?

Tags: php

Say I have the following:

```
$var = "1234567890";
```

I want it to appear as:

```
1234 567 890
```

With the first four numbers, a space, then three numbers, a space, then three numbers.

How can I do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: how sure are you of your input? If you know it's going to be 10 digits 100% of the time, then you could use substr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
echo substr($var, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($var, 4, 3) . ' ' . substr($var, 7, 3);
```

Before doing this, however, you should probably check to make sure the string is the length you expect it to be and has only numeric characters in it, like so:

```
if (strlen($var) == 10 && is_numeric($var))
{
    // $var passed the check
}
else
{
    // $var failed the check
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is a valid 10-digit number:

```
echo substr( $var, 0, 4 ) . ' ' . substr( $var, 4, 3 ) . ' ' . substr( $var, 7 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't too particular, you can do:

```
$var = substr($var,0,4)." ".substr($var,4,3)." ".substr($var,7);
```

This will break it up as you describe, and as a "bonus" it'll return an unlimited number of additional characters on the end if input is larger than expected.  Alternatively you could do

```
$var = substr($var,0,4)." ".substr($var,4,3)." ".substr($var,7,3);
```

to truncate digits past the 10th.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex:

```
$var = preg_replace("@(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})@", "\\1 \\2 \\3", $var);
```

Or, to be more precise:

```
$var = preg_replace("@^(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})$@", "\\1 \\2 \\3", $var);
```